# Instancing with OpenGL 3.3 seems very slow

Tags: c++, performance, opengl, matrix, geometry-instancing

I wrote a minimal code-sample in C++, which is rendering 10000 colored
quads on the screen. I am using "instancing" and so updating only
the model-matrix for each quad each frame. The data of the 6 vertices
are stored in an indivdual VBO und will be reused all the time.
The projection-matrix (orthographic) is injected once at program-start
via uniform. The model-matrix is calculated on the CPU with the library GLM.
I measured the rendering-time and I got only an average FPS of 52.
I think this is MUCH to less, but I cannot find the mistake/bottleneck in my little sample program.

After some analysis it seems, that the 3 calculations done with GLM
are very slow. Am I doing something wrong here? For example, If
I remove the rotating-calculation, I get an FPS-boost of 10 FPS!
Maybe you can help me to find out, what I can do better here and how
can I optimize my sample. It is important for me, that each quad is individual configurable during runtime, so I decided to use instancing.
Moving the matrix-calculations to the GPU seems another option, but I am really confused, why the CPU has so much problems calculating the 10000
model-matrices! Ok, my CPU is very bad (Athlon 2 Core-Duo M300, GPU is ATI Mobility Radeon 4100), but It should do this task in no measurable time, or?

Here is minimal, fully working, compilable example (If u have GLFW and GLM).
Maybe someone have some time and can help me out here :)

```
#define GLEW_STATIC
#define GLM_FORCE_INLINE
#define GLM_FORCE_SSE2
#include "glew.h"
#include "glfw3.h"
#include "glm.hpp"
#include "glm/gtc/matrix_transform.hpp"
#include <conio.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>

GLuint buildShader()
{
    std::string strVSCode = 
    "#version 330 core\n"
    "in vec3 vertexPosition;\n"
    "in mat4 modelMatrix;\n"
    "uniform mat4 projectionMatrix;\n"
    "out vec4 m_color;\n"
    "void main() {\n"
    "   vec4 vecVertex = vec4(vertexPosition, 1);\n"
    "   gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelMatrix * vecVertex;\n"
    "   m_color = gl_Position;\n"
    "}\n";

    std::string strFSCode = "#version 330 core\n"
    "out vec4 frag_colour;\n"
    "in vec4 m_color;\n"
    "void main() {\n"
    "   frag_colour = vec4(m_color.x, m_color.y, m_color.z, 0.5f);\n"
    "}\n";

    GLuint gluiVertexShaderId = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    char const * VertexSourcePointer = strVSCode.c_str();
    glShaderSource(gluiVertexShaderId, 1, &VertexSourcePointer, NULL);
    glCompileShader(gluiVertexShaderId);
    GLuint gluiFragmentShaderId = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    char const * FragmentSourcePointer = strFSCode.c_str();
    glShaderSource(gluiFragmentShaderId, 1, &FragmentSourcePointer, NULL);
    glCompileShader(gluiFragmentShaderId);
    GLuint gluiProgramId = glCreateProgram();
    glAttachShader(gluiProgramId, gluiVertexShaderId);
    glAttachShader(gluiProgramId, gluiFragmentShaderId);
    glLinkProgram(gluiProgramId);
    glDeleteShader(gluiVertexShaderId);
    glDeleteShader(gluiFragmentShaderId);
    return gluiProgramId;
}

struct Sprite
{
    glm::vec3 position, dimension;
    float speed, rotation, rx, ry;
};

struct Vertex
{
    float x, y, z;
    Vertex(){};
    Vertex(float x, float y, float z) : x(x), y(y), z(z) {}
};

int main(int arc, char **argv)
{
    // GLFW init
    int displayResWith   = 1366; //modify this here
    int displayResHeight = 768;  //modify this here
    glfwInit();
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, 1);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_RED_BITS, 8);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_GREEN_BITS, 8);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_BLUE_BITS, 8);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_ALPHA_BITS, 8);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_DEPTH_BITS, 32);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_STENCIL_BITS, 32);
    GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow(displayResWith, displayResHeight,"Instancing", glfwGetPrimaryMonitor(),NULL);
    int width, height;
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
    glfwSwapInterval(0);
    glfwGetFramebufferSize(window, &width, &height);

    //GLEW init
    glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;
    glewInit();
    const GLubyte* renderer = glGetString(GL_RENDERER);
    const GLubyte* version = glGetString(GL_VERSION);
    std::cout << "Renderer: " << renderer << std::endl;
    std::cout << "OpenGL supported version: " << version << std::endl;

    //OpenGL init
    glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE); 
    glCullFace(GL_BACK);
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glDepthFunc(GL_LESS);
    glEnable(GL_BLEND);
    glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
    glClearColor(255.0f, 255.0f, 255.0f, 255.0f);

    //Shader
    GLuint programID = buildShader();

    //VBO vertexBuffer
    GLuint vertexBuffer;
    glGenBuffers(1, &vertexBuffer);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexBuffer);
    Vertex VertexBufferData[6];
    VertexBufferData[0] = Vertex(-0.5f, 0.5f, 0.0f);    //Links oben
    VertexBufferData[1] = Vertex(-0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f);   //Links unten
    VertexBufferData[2] = Vertex(0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f);    //Rechts unten
    VertexBufferData[3] = VertexBufferData[2];          //Rechts unten
    VertexBufferData[4] = Vertex(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.0f);     //Rechts oben
    VertexBufferData[5] = VertexBufferData[0];          //Links oben
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(Vertex)*6, VertexBufferData, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    //VBO instanceBuffer
    GLuint instanceBuffer;
    glGenBuffers(1, &instanceBuffer);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, instanceBuffer);
    int iMaxInstanceCount = 30000;
    glm::mat4 *ptrInstanceBufferData = new glm::mat4[iMaxInstanceCount];
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, iMaxInstanceCount * sizeof(glm::mat4), NULL, GL_STREAM_DRAW);

    //VAO - Start
    GLuint vertexArrayObject;
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &vertexArrayObject);
    glBindVertexArray(vertexArrayObject);

        //For VBO vertexbuffer
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(glGetAttribLocation(programID, "vertexPosition"));
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexBuffer);
        glVertexAttribPointer(
            glGetAttribLocation(programID, "vertexPosition"),
            3,                                                  
            GL_FLOAT,                                           
            GL_FALSE,                                           
            sizeof(Vertex),                                     
            (void*)0                                            
            );

        glVertexAttribDivisor(0, 0);

        //For VBO instanceBuffer
        int pos = glGetAttribLocation(programID, "modelMatrix");
        int pos1 = pos + 0;
        int pos2 = pos + 1;
        int pos3 = pos + 2;
        int pos4 = pos + 3;
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(pos1);
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(pos2);
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(pos3);
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(pos4);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, instanceBuffer);
        glVertexAttribPointer(pos1, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(GLfloat) * 4 * 4, (void*)(0));
        glVertexAttribPointer(pos2, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(GLfloat) * 4 * 4, (void*)(sizeof(float) * 4));
        glVertexAttribPointer(pos3, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(GLfloat) * 4 * 4, (void*)(sizeof(float) * 8));
        glVertexAttribPointer(pos4, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(GLfloat) * 4 * 4, (void*)(sizeof(float) * 12));
        glVertexAttribDivisor(pos1, 1);
        glVertexAttribDivisor(pos2, 1);
        glVertexAttribDivisor(pos3, 1);
        glVertexAttribDivisor(pos4, 1);

    glBindVertexArray(0); //VAO - End

    //Matrix vars
    glm::mat4 Projection, Rotating, Scaling, Translation, Identity;
    glm::vec3 ZRotateVec(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);

    //Calc projection-matrix and put shader (uniform)
    Projection = glm::ortho(0.0f, (float)width, 0.0f, (float)height, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    glUseProgram(programID);
    glUniformMatrix4fv(glGetUniformLocation(programID, "projectionMatrix"), 1, GL_FALSE, &Projection[0][0]);

    //Creating sprites
    std::srand(static_cast<unsigned int>(std::time(0)));
    int iActInstanceCount = 10000;
    Sprite *ptrSprites = new Sprite[iActInstanceCount];
    for (int i = 0; i < iActInstanceCount; ++i)
    {
        ptrSprites[i].dimension = glm::vec3(16, 16, 1.0f);
        ptrSprites[i].position = glm::vec3(std::rand()%(width-32),std::rand()%(height-32),-1.0f *((std::rand()%256)/256.0f));
        ptrSprites[i].rotation = rand() % 360 + 0.0f;
        ptrSprites[i].rx = static_cast<float>(std::rand() % 2);
        ptrSprites[i].ry = static_cast<float>(std::rand() % 2);
        ptrSprites[i].speed = (std::rand() % 100) + 1.0f;
        if (ptrSprites[i].speed < 1.0f) ptrSprites[i].speed = 1.0f;
    }

    //FPS init
    double fFramesRendered = 0.0f;
    double fFrameMeasurementStart = 0.0f;
    double fFPS = 0.0f;
    double fCurrentTime = 0.0f;
    glfwSetTime(0);

    //Main-loop (also renderloop)
    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
    {
        //application-logic
        if (glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE)== GLFW_PRESS)
            glfwSetWindowShouldClose(window, GL_TRUE);

        const double fNewTime = glfwGetTime();
        double fDeltaTime = fNewTime - fCurrentTime;
        fCurrentTime = fNewTime;

        for (int i = 0; i < iActInstanceCount; ++i)
        {
            float fSpeed = ptrSprites[i].speed * static_cast<float>(fDeltaTime);
            ptrSprites[i].rotation += fSpeed;
            if (ptrSprites[i].rotation >= 360.0f) ptrSprites[i].rotation = 0.0f;
            if (ptrSprites[i].rx == 1)  ptrSprites[i].position.x = ptrSprites[i].position.x + fSpeed;
            if (ptrSprites[i].rx == 0)  ptrSprites[i].position.x = ptrSprites[i].position.x - fSpeed;
            if (ptrSprites[i].ry == 1)  ptrSprites[i].position.y = ptrSprites[i].position.y + fSpeed;
            if (ptrSprites[i].ry == 0)  ptrSprites[i].position.y = ptrSprites[i].position.y - fSpeed;
            if (ptrSprites[i].position.x <= 0) ptrSprites[i].rx = 1;
            if (ptrSprites[i].position.x + ptrSprites[i].dimension.x >= width) ptrSprites[i].rx = 0;
            if (ptrSprites[i].position.y <= 0) ptrSprites[i].ry = 1;
            if (ptrSprites[i].position.y + ptrSprites[i].dimension.y >= height) ptrSprites[i].ry = 0;

            //matrix-calculations (saved in local buffer)
            Translation = glm::translate(Identity, ptrSprites[i].position + glm::vec3(ptrSprites[i].dimension.x / 2.0f, ptrSprites[i].dimension.y / 2.0f, 0.0f));
            Scaling = glm::scale(Translation, ptrSprites[i].dimension);
            ptrInstanceBufferData[i] = glm::rotate(Scaling, ptrSprites[i].rotation, ZRotateVec);
        }

        //render-call
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
        glUseProgram(programID);
        glBindVertexArray(vertexArrayObject);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, instanceBuffer);
        glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, iMaxInstanceCount * sizeof(glm::mat4), NULL, GL_STREAM_DRAW); // Buffer orphaning
        glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, iActInstanceCount * sizeof(glm::mat4), ptrInstanceBufferData);
        glDrawArraysInstanced(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 6, iActInstanceCount);
        glBindVertexArray(0);
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
        glfwPollEvents();


        //FPS-stuff
        ++fFramesRendered;

        if ((fCurrentTime*1000.0f) >= (fFrameMeasurementStart*1000.0f) + 1000.0f)
        {
            fFPS = ((fCurrentTime*1000.0f) - (fFrameMeasurementStart*1000.0f)) / 1000.0f * fFramesRendered;
            fFrameMeasurementStart = fCurrentTime;
            fFramesRendered = 0;
            std::cout << "FPS: " << fFPS << std::endl;
        }
    }

    //Termination and cleanup
    glDeleteBuffers(1, &vertexBuffer);
    glDeleteBuffers(1, &instanceBuffer);
    glDeleteVertexArrays(1, &vertexArrayObject);
    glDeleteProgram(programID);
    glfwDestroyWindow(window);
    glfwTerminate();
    return _getch();
}
```

Comment: I think, in your example, calculating those matrices on the CPU will be the main bottleneck. In that scenario, it could be worth a try to not pre-calculate the matrices on the CPU. As I understand, you have a 2D position, 2D scale factor and a single rotation angle per instance, so you could just sent these packed to 2 vectors to the GPU, and construct the matrixes on the fly in the vertex shader. Since you draw only one quad, this will mean that the GPU will have to do 4 times the work (if you use GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP instead of the 6 vertices per instance), but it might still be worth it.

Comment: (continued) Note that tranlsation and scaling can be done more efficiently directly on the input vector by add or mul, so no need to build a full matrix. Only rotation will need a bit more effort, but in 2D, it is quite easy, you just need `sin` and `cos`. Having said that, since you only work in 2D, you could also simplify the CPU code. No need for 4x4 matrices. Coneceptually, a 2x3 matrix is enough to encode all of the operations you need, so there is a huge potential for optimizations even if you keep carrying this out on the CPU.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, after testing it on my machine, it is definitely CPU limited, so nothing you do with OGL is going to make much difference. I get about ~300fps with GCC on at least -O1, but only ~80 with -O0. My CPU is very fast (i7 2600k, 4.7ghz), but my GPU is rather slow (GT 520). I'm also on Ubuntu.

Some quick ideas for things that might speed it up a little:

- Put the vertex positions in an array in the vertex shader and use gl_VertexID to access them
- Use GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP instead of GL_TRIANGLES
- Use radians for angles, as otherwise GLM has to convert them

None of these are likely to make much of any impact, really. Just make sure your compiler is set up right, and there probably isn't much more to do.